# I want to write a query to print sum of data for all TC into single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query to select distinct `TCName` values from a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TCName) 
FROM [dbo].[TCDetails]
```

This is another query to sum a data into table:

```
SELECT 
    sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS,
    sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount
FROM [Customer] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS 
    ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC 
    ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
```

I want to write a query so that I am able to print sum of data for all TC into single table

I try this but It's not working

```
SELECT 
    sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS,
    sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount
FROM [Customer] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS 
    ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC 
    ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID 
WHERE TCName in 
    (
    Select distinct
        (TCName)
    FROM [dbo].[TCDetails]
    )
```

I wanted to print it like

```
  TCName  | sum(BS.BLDOS) | sum(BS.CollectedAmount)
  xyz     | 23456         |  6755
  tyu     | 34556         |  567898
  bnv     | 21467         |  345
```

Comment: what data is your current query giving?

Comment: What does your result look like, if you can share?

Comment: "Not working" means you get an error message, no records, too many records, wrong records? What?

Comment: [dbo].[TCName] Looks like a table name to me, but you use it as a column name.

Comment: Sum of all records in single row but i want to calculate it for each TCName

Comment: Oops! sorry  @ThorstenKettner its my typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by` if you want multiple rows in the output

```
  SELECT TCName, sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS, sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount
  FROM [Customer] C INNER JOIN
       [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS
       ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID INNER JOIN
       [dbo].[TCDetails] TC 
       ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
  WHERE TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails])
  GROUP BY TCName;
```